# Dispose of a ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android

I am using ProgressDialog to display a spinner while a Thread is running. When the thread is finished, the dialog is removed from the view and another Activity is pushed onto the stack. The problem is, the dialog is not disposed of. When I go back to the Activity (pop the stack) and return to the previous Activity, the same instance of the ProgressDialog is being called (when asked to show dialog).

Create the dialog:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) { 

 progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
 progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
 progDialog.setMessage("Searching for ..." + txtPart.getText().toString());
 // Start thread            
 progThread = new AcmXmlSearchHelper(handler, txtTitle.getText().toString(), txtPart.getText().toString(), txtSection.getText().toString(), this);
 progThread.start();
 return progDialog;

}
```

Show the dialog:

```
showDialog(getProgressId());
```

Dismiss the dialog:

```
dismissDialog(getProgressId());
```

The easy solution is to call a ProgressDialog (showDialog()) with a unique id. However, I don't think this is good use of memory. I could have a number of Dialogs hanging around in memory. How do I make sure the object is disposed?

Thx

Comment: Where do you call `showDialog()`? In `onCreate()`, `onResume()`?

Comment: @Phil: user802421's comment may be relevant. To quote your question..."When the thread is finished, the dialog is removed from the view..." - if this is the case and it truly is dismissed but you see it when you return from the second Activity, then it suggests the code which created it in the first place is being called a second time. By the way, is there a reason why you are using a `Thread` instead of `AsyncTask`? Using `AsyncTask` makes handling progress / alert dialogs very easy using its `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods.

Comment: Thanks I will looking AsyncTask. To answer @user802421's question, the showDialog() is called when a onClick Event.

Comment: We are near to the cause of the problem. Where do you call `dismissDialog()`. Does `getProgressId()` return the same value as when calling `showDialog()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a nested AsyncTask class would probably clear things up for you:

```
private static class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

           protected void onPreExecute() {
               // Show dialog here - note: showDialog is depricated.
           }

            protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
                    // do the stuff that's in your thread here.
                    return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                    // Dismiss dialog here - note: dismissDialog is depricated.
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use `removeDialog(id)` instead of `dismissDialog(id)`.